# Getting top N tags attached to each object in Django

Tags: python, django

With following models:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Review(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='review')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='review')
```

I want to prefetch top three tags for each Restaurant object like below.

```py
Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('review__tags', queryset=tag_qs))
```

But I'm having difficulty specifying tag_qs, which may be something like below

```py
tag_qs = Tag.objects.annotate(restaurant=F('review__restaurant'))
                    .  # What more should I do?
```

How can I get tag_qs so that it contains top three tags for each Restaurant object?